# Redis v/s php mysql

Tags: mysql, nosql, redis

I am new to redis and started with the following link 
http://www.aspieschool.com/wiki/index.php?title=Redis_vs_MySQL_(Benchmarks)
Which shows that `My sql write` is taking less time than `redis write` and redis read is taking less time than `mysql read`. but in my case, scenario is just opposite .
I am using following code to write into mysql :

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die('unable to connect ');
}
mysql_select_db("redistest",$con);
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++){
    $query = "insert into `test`(`name`) values ('Rohit')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```

It is taking approx 3 minutes and in redis I am using the code as follow :

```
require 'predis-0.8/autoload.php';

$single_server = array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 15
);

$multiple_servers = array(
    array(
       'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
       'port'     => 6379,
       'database' => 15,
       'alias'    => 'first',
    ),
    array(
       'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
       'port'     => 6380,
       'database' => 15,
       'alias'    => 'second',
    ),
);

// simple set and get scenario
$time_start = microtime(true);
$client = new Predis\Client($single_server);
$client->flushall();
for($i=0;$i<5000;$i++){
echo $client->lPush('key8', 'C');
echo "<br>";
}
//$retval = $client->get('rohit');
//$ass = array();
//$ass = $client->lrange('key8',0,-1);
//foreach($ass as $ass)
//echo "<br/>$ass";
$time_end = microtime(true);

$diff = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br/>".$diff;
//var_dump($retval);
```

and it is taking approx 1.292163848877 seconds:

In reading from mysql :

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die('unable to connect ');
}
mysql_select_db("redistest",$con);
$sql="select * from `test`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    foreach($results as $results)
        $results."<br/>";
}
$time_end = microtime(true);

$diff = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br/>".$diff;
?>
```

it is taking approx 0.040173053741455 seconds

And using redis :

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
$client = new Predis\Client($single_server);
//$client->flushall();
//for($i=0;$i<5000;$i++){
//echo $client->lPush('key8', 'C');
//echo "<br>";
//}
//$retval = $client->get('rohit');
$ass = array();
$ass = $client->lrange('key8',0,-1);
foreach($ass as $ass)
//echo "<br/>$ass";
$time_end = microtime(true);

$diff = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br/>".$diff;
```

It is approx taking time 0.13404297828674 seconds. Can anyone suggest me that where I am going wrong, ?

Comment: I don't know much about redis, but you can increase mysql write speeds massively if you have innodb tables and do the insert inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This benchmark is not worthwhile looking at. So much variables (network latency, native extension against non-native one, ACID  ...) are not taken into account and comparing MySQL against Redis does not make any sense.

---

First thing first, I suspect that your MySQL database is an InnoDB one, that's why the inserts take so much time.

Your results feel much more right to me than the benchmark. Redis being a in-memory database (with optional durability) it should always be faster at write ops that an ACID database like MySQL. Too bad I can't find what version of Redis and MySQL were used.

Another explanation for MySQL being faster than Redis from PHP is that the MySQL driver for PHP is a native one while Predis is written in pure PHP. But that's still weird as I never heard of someone complaining about Predis slowness.

In short don't use [predis in a *high-traffic* production site](http://www.quora.com/Redis/How-does-PRedis-compare-with-phpredis) use [PhpIRedis](https://github.com/nrk/phpiredis) instead.

---

Full-disclosure: I'm the founder of **[GUI Client for Redis: Redsmin](http://redsmin.com)**.